# Sum of Results Python SQL Query

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

**Current code:**

```
 import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

if connection:
        print("Yes we connected\n")

cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute(SELECT cost1 FROM tbl)

data = cur.fetchall()

for row in data:
        print(row)
```

I admit I have almost no idea what I am doing in python and I got slapped with a project a little while ago that is do ASA-yesterday. I need to be able to take the results from the SQL query and sum them together. Or store them in variables to where I can call back to them in an equation.

**Results are:**
10,
431,
543,
1268,
1207

**Expected Result:**
3459

I am more than happy to give any more information, and I will be spending the interim continuing to research.

Comment: you can sum the row values if they integer if not convert them to integer before the addition

Comment: They are number values, they actually have decimals. I just truncated them for the example. Can I still sum the rows if they are numbers values? And is it just print(sum(row))?

Comment: No, `data` is a list which contains numbers, row is just one of those numbers so you can't use `sum(row)`. You can add row values to a variable one-by-one but you can use `sum` function for `data`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only after the sum and not the individual numbers then the easiest way is to do that in SQL:

```
query = 'select sum(cost1) from tbl'
```

If you want the individual numbers also then.:

```
cur.execute(SELECT cost1 FROM tbl)

data = cur.fetchall()
tot = 0
for row in data:
        print(row)
        tot += row[0]
print(tot)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was not able to sum it in SQL as it is a much bigger query than shown. Your second result works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

your SQL query should be modified to `SELECT sum(cost1) FROM tbl`

or you can get the results in the python, and sum them...
otherwise you are just getting a list of values in the column cost1

or in python you can do:

```
import pyodbc

connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

if connection:
        print("Yes we connected\n")

cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute(SELECT cost1 FROM tbl)

data = cur.fetchall()
sum = 0
for row in data:
        sum = sum + row
print(sum)
```

Comment: The SQL query is actually massive, and I can't sum it there unfortunately. I've been doing some research and cannot find a solution the works for summing the columns in python.

Comment: added a pythonic solution for the sum as well

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to go adding row by row:**

```
import pyodbc
connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQLServer};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)

if connection:
    print("Yes we connected\n")

cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT sum(cost1) FROM tbl;')
x=cur.fetchone()[0]
print(x) # x will hold the value of the sum
```

Have a great day.